# CSS order elements right to left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have the text inside the "header rectangle"(darker purple) and place the heart image on the right side of the text like this

[image]

**BUT** I'm getting this result

[image]

with this `html` code

```
<div class="row book-header">
  <div class="col-lg-4 text-right d-none d-lg-block avatar">
    <img src="assets/images/avatar.svg">        
    <span class="name" >Hi Helana</span><br>
    <span class="message">How are you today?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

or this one

[image]

with this `html` code:

```
<div class="row book-header">
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-right d-none d-lg-block avatar">
        <img src="assets/images/avatar.svg">
        <div> 
        <span class="name" >Hi Helana</span><br>
            <span class="message">How are you today?</span>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

my `css` code is:

```
.book-header{
    background-image: linear-gradient(269.78deg, #632095 0%, #4AC3E8 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 7.52083px 7.52083px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 64px;
    z-index: 300;
    
    .avatar{
        img {
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            margin-right: 20%;
            margin-top: 1.5%;
        }
        .name {
            margin-right: 32%;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 0.2em 2em;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-weight: 600 !important;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .message {
            margin-right: 32%;
            padding: 2em;               
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: right;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-weight: normal !important;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what do you want ?

Comment: @decpk edited the question, and added an image with the wanted result

Answer (score 0):

Create a `wrapper` on both of the `span` and use `flex` on the `header-wrapper` container. I've simulated the image with the `emoticon`. You can use image also.

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

You just need to add the below classes in the `header-wrapper` if you are using `bootstrap` and remove the `css`.

```
d-lg-flex flex-row-reverse justify-content-between align-items-center
```

```css
.header-wrapper{
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row book-header">
  <div class="col-lg-4 text-right d-none d-lg-block avatar header-wrapper">
    <div class="image">☺</div>
    <div>
      <span class="name" >Hi Helana</span><br>
      <span class="message">How are you today?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using Bootstrap. Have you checked your solution works with Bootstrap included?

Comment: Added its class also. Thanks for suggestion ☺

Comment: @decpk using your code with the real image results like my second try --> the text appear under the book header (the purple rectancle)